# Transfer data to arduino via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I am planning to transfer data between arduino and a mobile device. Right now, I can read data from arduino in mobile device, but can't send data to the arduino board. here is the code I am using for data transfer:

> **Android Code:**
>
> ```
> void sendData() throws IOException {
>   String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
>   msg += "\n";
>   mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
>   //mmOutputStream.write('A');
>   myLabel.setText("Data Sent"+msg.getBytes());       }
> ```
>
> **Arduino Code:**
>
> ```
>      SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);
>
>      void loop() {     
>        char aChar = bluetooth.read();
>        Serial.print(aChar); 
>       }
> ```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously my Tx and Rx was set to:

```
int bluetoothTx = 2;  // TX-O pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D2
int bluetoothRx = 3;  // RX-I pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D3
```

I changed the pin to:

```
int bluetoothTx = 8;  // TX-O pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D8
int bluetoothRx = 10;  // RX-I pin of bluetooth mate, Arduino D10
```

Now it's working porperly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added a small delay when sending data from the Arduino. Here is an example.

```
void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        char data = Serial.read();
        Serial.print(data);
    }

    delay(5);
}
```

Comment: I also tried with your code, but for some reason it doesn't work. It shows a sequence of "ÿÿÿÿÿÿ"